# Apache hive Query on bucketed column

Tags: hive, bucket

I have created one bucketed table on timeslot column which has value from 0  to 23 and datatype of timeslot column is int

I have created 24 buckets and load 10000000 rows (6GB of data) in the bucketed table

At the same time i created a normal non-bucketed table using same dataset

later I queried on bucketed table as well as non-bucketed table like as below

```
select * from bucketed_table where timeslot = 15;

select * from non-bucketed_table where timeslot = 15;
```

both the queries are taking almost same time

I was assuming bucketed table perform far better than non-bucketed table

can anyone let me know if i am doing something wrong or my assumption is completely wrong?

Comment: Which format are you using for that file? Did you check how many physical files were created in each table? Are you aware that an INSERT command does *not* automatically honor the bucketing specification unless you set `hive.enforce.bucketing` cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables ?

Comment: I am using simple text format for both tables, I also set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;while inserting data into bucketed table and also checked 24 files are created there in bucketed table also at the time of inserting data 24 reducers launched to create different bucket files.

Comment: How many mappers does Hive run in parallel to read the non-bucketed table? Because with a 256 MB block size, a single 6 GB file means 24 blocks which can be read by 24 mappers in parallel. So it should be almost as fast as the bucketed table which reads just 1 block... but consume 24 times the CPU and 24 times the I/O. It all depends on what you mean by "better"!

Comment: 25 mappers are created for both bucketed and non bucketed table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding bucketed table only performed better in case of joining with other bucketed table. if we just query on bucketed column there will not be any performance gain as in this case both bucketed table and non-bucketed table scan whole table (data files) and that is why in both the cases same number of mapper are launched